# How to split the dev-server.js file in vue to several separated files?

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

I am using vue.js to compose a app, and I mocked a login api of localhost in dev-server.js, now I want to separate the code about login api into a independent file, what should I do? Besides there are some code about CORS, here is the code:

```
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var multer = require('multer')
var upload = multer()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
// CORS
var allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Token')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
  next()
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain)



// mock localhost api
var apiRoutes = express.Router()
// login api;
const userAccountList = ['100000', '100001', '100002', '100003']
apiRoutes.post('/user/login', upload.array(), function (req, res) {
  if (userAccountList.indexOf(req.body.account) < 0){
    return res.json({
      code: 50000,
      msg: 'the account or the password is not correct, please try again'
    });
  }
}
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I think it's a question about node and express, instead of vue.js)

While express is basically built web app with middleware, I think it's time to split your logic into different middleware.

So you can put your login logic into a independent .js file as a middleware like:

```
// login.js

const userAccountList = ['100000', '100001', '100002', '100003']

const loginMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  if (userAccountList.indexOf(req.body.account) < 0){
    res.json({
      code: 50000,
      msg: 'the account or the password is not correct, please try again'
    });
  }
};

module.exports = loginMiddleware;
```

Then requiring it from your app like:

```
// app.js

const loginMiddleware = require('./login');

// ...

apiRoutes.post('/user/login', loginMiddleware);
```

Here is the official express document about how to write your middleware properly: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: By the way, there is a official middleware for CORS: https://github.com/expressjs/cors. So you don't need to write it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out a module bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). It allows you to split code into different bundles which can be loaded together.